# CloseCom and such, any idea where that come from ? (C++)

Tags: c++

I have an old project in c++ that i need to recompile for windows 7.
there were some .MAK files, and i managed to open one of them with visual studio 6

The problem is that there are several error when i try to compile as is.
One of those error that i can't seem to fix is about several comm functions :

CloseComm
GetCommError
ReadComm
WriteComm

I thought it was because one file wasn't included, but after searching the only places where thoses words come from are cpp files using the functions, not defining them.

Google wasn't really helpfull so i'm asking here if it ring a bell to someone.

thank you and sorry for my english :)

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx – Essentially, your code is using 16 bit functions that are no longer supported and need to be replaced.

Comment: Blimey! Those were 16-bit Windows functions - how old is that code?

Comment: pretty old indeed. Thank you for the help, i will look at it.